# Best practices on debates in comments?

Tags: discussion

One of our users, [Victor](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/5466/victor), constantly makes comments implying that it returns of 30% or 40% per year are reasonable using trailing stops and careful picking. Victor is a valuable poster with good reputation and a significant number of great answers and comments.

His advice often leads to back-and-forth debates in comments. For example, [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/what-does-the-term-match-the-market-mean/21477#21477) and [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/why-is-the-dominant-investing-advice-for-individuals-to-use-mfs-etfs-etc/20999#comment28606_20999).

My question is whether this community views such back-and-forth debates as a good thing or a bad thing. If good, how could the debate be improved? If bad, is there a way we could point questioners to the theories without arguing in the comments?

Comment: I'm not sure how to inform Victor about this thread; could someone do so, if appropriate? Also, to be clear, this question is in NO way a personal attack. I like the back-and-forth, just not sure if it is appropriate for the site. If it isn't, I'm at least as much to blame as Victor is.

Comment: FWIW, such back-and-forth discussion is why the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money) exists.

Comment: I pointed this meta question out to Victor on one of the comment threads.

Answer (score 8):

Comments are comment on the question / answer.  While there are exceptions to everything, once comments get meta (commenting about comments) I view them negatively.  Two people having a discussion or argument below a question only dilutes the value of what they are "commenting" on.

I wouldn't suggest automatically deleting comments on other comments, but I would suggest that 4 or more back and forth exchanges get seriously considered for deletion. Once each person as said something twice, off to the chat it should go.

- Comments on the answer or question are valuable, especially if they offer dissent
- Comments aimed at other comments should be discouraged.  (Comment on the main content)
- More than four rounds of back and fourth, comments are in big danger of being deleted

We want to encourage clarification, criticism and dissent.  We don't want to encourage chatting.

Comment: Also, @Victor and other passionate people should understand strong positions will elicit strong responses.  Speaking for myself, I value everybody's opinions and the passionate ones especially.  Don't be discouraged, I learn a lot from y'all.

Comment: I rather like this rule of thumb. Definitely gets a +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Chris - I am guilty of engaging in comment-chat with Victor. I feel compelled to point out to the casual reader the the expectations of such returns are not reasonable. 
The back and forth comments are a distraction, and should be kept to a minimum. I think it's for the user to know when to stop, and that failing, the mods are doing a good job cleaning things up. 
In most cases, trying to keep this general, there's a line where those going on should just 'agree to disagree.'